# MVC and Model responsibilities

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

I have a small Laravel project. In this project I have a few models, but the ones required for my question are `User`, `Course` and `Payment` models.

A `User` can *subscribe* to a `Course` (only one) and needs to pay a monthly amount for his subscription.

I'm creating a new page that will show different contents depending on the current status of the `User`. If they failed a payment, I will display `ContentA`, if all payments are up to date `ContentB` will be displayed.

Is it correct, from a MVC architecture point of view, to create a function in the `User` model `hasFailedPayments()` that will perform all required operations and checks to decide if the `User` has failed payments? Should this be a responsibility of one of the other layers (Controller/View)?

At the moment I'm making the checks in the Controller but if I need to do the exact same check I will need to duplicate this code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You are correct, this logic would live in the Model.  In most cases most or all of your business logic should live inside your models.  The View is there to see the data resulting from the logic. The controllers are there to serve the views with the models and control the overall flow of the project.

Comment: Also if your models start getting very large I would recommend putting them in a service provider, but outside of that E McG is correct.